# Script to list owners of sub-directories on a windows share

Tags: windows, powershell

All I need is a list of sub-directories, given a starting directory, listing the owner of that directory.

Any ideas on easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Get-ChildItem](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308) cmdlet to retrieve the sub-directories and determine the owner using the [Get-Acl](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113305) cmdlet:

```
Get-ChildItem '\\server\yourshare' | 
where PSIsContainer | 
select FullName, @{e={Get-Acl $_.FullName | select -expand Owner}; l="Owner"}
```